# Update one database table column with different values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update table with max three value and minimum with two values.How it would be possible to update table. I Get values from form, there are three fields for three students. Now all of them having same value when i update them in the database. Now i am trying this why. Dont know it works or not
See my page [image: This is the form where i get values from database and then want to update there are three student name fields (with different name and id in html form but at back end they are stored in one table column)]

```
$s1_name=$_POST['s1_name'];
$s2_name=$_POST['s2_name'];
$s3_name=$_POST['s3_name'];

$query="update students SET Name=:Name
WHERE ProjectID='$id'
";

try
{

 $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );  
 $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $s1_name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $s2_name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $s3_name);
 $result = $stmt->execute();
 $msg = "Record updated";
 }

 catch(PDOException $ex)
 {
  $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
 }

 }
```

Comment: column with different values you mean at first a = b then a = c then a = d like that? If so then why multiple update you can directly update a = d

Comment: yes because these are coming from different form fields. see the above picture

Comment: at backend they are stored in same table. with different registration number

Answer (score 0):

It does not work this way. The way you are doing it will result in the query only updating it for `$s3_name`.

You will have to do your try/catch statement for each query:

```
<?php

$names = [$_POST['s1_name'], $_POST['s2_name'], $_POST['s3_name']];
$query = "update students SET Name=:Name WHERE ProjectID='$id'";


foreach ($names as $name) {
    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $msg = "Record updated";
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {  
       $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: s3_name is shown in all three fields through this way

Comment: thanks for your response but it only display the last post['s3_name'] value in all three fields.@ThomasVdBerge